# Why did my solution fail to build overnight with the error "Failed to retrieve information from remote source"?

Tags: .net-core, nuget

We have a solution file which contains several projects which builds just fine on my computer using both "dotnet" CLI as well as Visual Studio 2017. Literally overnight, the build would fail, and I cannot associate the change that may have attributed to the failure. Both VS2017 and CLI failed with a message like this:

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.4\NuGet.targets(97,5): error : Failed to retrieve information about 'System.Xml.XmlDocument' from remote source 'D:\mtp\proj.vs\hello_proj\bin\Release\PublishOutput'. [D:\mtp\proj.vs\server-ray\my_solution.sln]

This is is misleading, as the hello_proj where this seems to indicate, is configured for building "Debug" as oppose to the "Release" shown. I have already attempted to clear out all cached packages, copied packages to where the solution resides, and copied the packages to where the error indicates, but I could not get over this error. Nuget is obviously getting some information somewhere to look for the packages in the wrong place, but I don't really know where it gets that info from. I also verified that the "missing" packages exist in the "global-packages" folder (found by running "nuget local all -list").

Answer (score 6):

I found something that fixed my problem; I searched for Nuget.Config in the entire C: drive and found one in %appdata%\Nuget\Nuget.config. I removed it and the build went through successfully. The Nuget.config was restored to some default values that fixed the problem. I can't explain it; just glad it worked.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that one of your dependencies is pointing to D: which could have been removed by any reason. I suggest you to delete the packages folder, find the dependency that refers to D: and remove and add it again from NuGet. By the end you can let Visual Studio restore all of dependencies.

Comment: One more bit of information I forgot to mention: This seems to be an problem specifically with my machine. The exact same source tree can be built successfully on other machines (multiple). There is some setting in my machine that is causing this.