# ASP.NET Core project missing all dependencies

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core

I've just cloned a repo with solution containing many projects and there seems to be problems with only .NET Core ones.

[image]

Building the project and restoring NuGet gives no results.
I've also tried

> dotnet restore

When I even try to right-click on "Dependencies" and "Add Reference..." VS is crushing every time.
Nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

My setup:

- Windows 10, build 10.0.15063
- Visual Studio 2017 (15.5)
- dotnet --version 2.1.4

Comment: What is the output given by `dotnet restore`? It will be too long to paste in a comment, but I'm wondering whether there's something in the output which might tell us why Visual Studio doesn't like the references. Also, is it a public repo?

Comment: Do you have latest dotnet core sdk installed? Just not much info provided to diagnose your issue

Comment: @JohanHerstad I've got dotnet core sdk 1.0.4, 1.1.0, 2.1.2 and 2.1.4 installed.

Comment: @JamieTaylor 'dotnet restore' just gives me the information that the restore completed in X seconds and nothing more. I've found something about adding     <RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x86</RuntimeIdentifier> in .csjproj along with <TargetFramework> which I had and the 'dotnet restore' downloaded all the libraries (at least that's how it looked) and still Visual Studio doesn't see dependencies.

Comment: Is it out of scope to paste a redacted, minimal version of the source code with recreates this issue?

Comment: The problem is that there is no error in the code. There is nothing in VS saying there is something wrong. 0 errors, some warnings not related to the issue. In .NET Core projects VS doesn't color the code and no compile time errors are shown. I can put wrong class name, namespace name etc...

Answer (score 0):

I've just encountered this issue, the solution was as posted by the OP over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45473462/dotnet-core-solution-failed-restore).

Basically, a rouge Nuget.Config had infiltrated the development environment and was misdirecting the package restore to a local directory, causing it to fail to find anything.